# What was the God-Emperor doing during World War 2?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Maybe related if you squint: [Is Doombreed Hitler?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/209673/70477)

We know that the God-Emperor of Mankind has lived for tens of thousands of years under different names, including Gilgamesh, Hercules, and St. George, as he slowly guided humanity in the shadows before emerging as a world leader in the Great Crusade in the early 31st millennium.

Of course, by the time of Warhammer 40k, the 20th century has been essentially forgotten by in-universe historians, but do we (the readers and players) know anything specific about what the Emperor was doing in World War 2?

Given the Emperor's personality, talents, and goals, I tend to imagine the Emperor as having been either as a warlord or an engineer. Considering the Emperor's views on the unity of humanity, it seems unlikely that he would have been a Nazi, but do we know where he was or whether he was someone we know?

Some of my thoughts on possible engineers include Mikhail Kalashnikov (designer of one of the best rifles of all time) or J. Robert Oppenheimer (developer of nuclear weapons). One personal headcanon I had was Antoine de Saint-Exupéry, a French military pilot and a writer who emphasized the unity of humanity who disappeared under mysterious circumstances (possibly because he never actually died, and just changed his name). Other possibilities include holding some important but non-famous role in the war, such as an ordinary Soviet tank driver or a British platoon sergeant.

Is there any official Warhammer 40k material that hints at who the emperor was and what he was doing during the war?

Comment: Have you *looked* at the Imperium under the Emperor? Xenophobic, officially non-religious but with many cults of personality around its leader, genocidal, and all that Reich-style pagentry—I think it is clear who the Emperor would have been, if anyone.

Comment: Not to mention all of his Übermenschen super-soldiers born from his fun eugenics experiments. And of course "humans (except for mutants and psykers) are the master species" is just "Aryans (except for gay people and those with disabilities) are the master race" with thirty thousand years to marinate.

Comment: @Shade it doesn't have an answer that does, but the question would cover this one.